# best way to create sort order in the Cursor in android?

Tags: android, android-cursor

Is creating different cursor for creating sort orders and distribute it in an model clases for alternating sorting style in an listview in android good practice?

```
titleCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
                null, null, orderByTitle);

timeCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
                null, null, orderByTime);

dateCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
                null, null, orderByDate);
```

and values of its cursor will be destributed to each models to get the cursor for sorting for alternating sorting in listview? is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new cursor.  You can just change the sort value for the query, if all other things remain constant.  That's why it's a parameter, so you alter it's value upon execution of the query.

Comment: if i change the sort value the listview also will refresh? how to do it in runtime after the listview is already displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a different cursor for each sort, you could maintain a string value or some integer value and based on the value inside an if condition simply change the sort parameter like:

```
if(value.equals("time")) {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
            null, null, orderByTime);

}else if(value.equals("title")) {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
            null, null, orderByTitle);
}
```

and so on.

Comment: what i mean during runtime, after the listview use the cursor and already display, is it posbile to change the order of the cursor and listview refresh?

Comment: The easiest way  is by re-running the query.  That way you don't have to worry about reordering the data yourself.  Since your doing this with a database you'll want to use newView and bindView as opposed to getView.  The onClick goes in the bindView.  If you need a more extensive example, let me know, I could put one up tomorrow.  The Android framework is a that a listview is serviced data by an array adapter and in your case, the array adapter is feed   from a database.  The frameworks are in place so that you can change the data presentation and not have to worry about the plumbing.

Comment: ahh i get it now using adapter.swapCursor(), and used adapter.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), i have a bigger mistery right now, because of some api in android im returing back to java im restudying the collection classes right now, im still cannot get why some other programer says POJO is good than using Cursor in android? im still confused right now, if android support like requery why other programmer said still used java way like pojo like collections clases than using android predefined classes?

Comment: A POJO is a Plain Old Java Object, it's kind of on the same level as a database, a data object.  It should have getters and setters, etc.   for managing the data content, where as the with a SQLite database you have it's CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) methods i.e. Insert, Update, Delete, Query setup in your Content Provider. Since your already using a database, I wouldn't worry about a POJO.  You would use either a POJO or a Content Provider not both for the same data.  With a Content Provider you have more flexibility.  It's a design / requirement choice: Content Provider or POJO.

Comment: ahh so if i want yo used POJO so stick with POJO if i want to use android predefined api like content provider so stick with android content provider..thnx!

Comment: follow up question, i have a project wich is working, a listview that populate data from sdcard using cursor to get MediaData using mediastore, and in adapter using simplecursor adapter. Question is if using java way is there a way to get data of the Video from the sdcard without using cursor, and using the POJO style?  like getting video data from the sdcard put it in the collection classes and interfaces and act as my model class without using any cursor or model class, just java way? is it posible and when it comes to performance wich is good from both when it comes to listview?